# Rolling a simple ESB/Discovery service in C#?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation, esb, ws-discovery

In looking around at the various ESBs and discovery services I've found a few things that are close to what i want (NServiceBus, the sample in .NET StockTrader, etc.) but have not been able to find a concise tutorial on the correct way to roll my own discovery/bus framework.. Is there anything I can reference when going through the process of building out a distributed ESB?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us some specifics around what you're trying to achieve, which isnt covered by any of the existing ESB products available?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to build an ESB if you can use NServiceBus, Phoenix Service Bus, and e.t.c?

Comment: Its mostly a learning exercise.. I'm having a hard time getting the relationships between WS-Discovery, service tracking, and ESB.